# How to install Java native development headers on OS X Lion

Tags: java, java-native-interface, osx-lion

I'm trying to build a JNI project, but I can't seem to find the JNI headers (e.g. `jni.h`). I've installed "Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Developer Package" from https://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

Various online resources suggest the headers should be in locations such as `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers` or `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include`, but I can't find them anywhere -- the installer doesn't seem to be creating them.

I see other JDK components -- just for example, `/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Commands/javah` -- but not the JNI headers. Any suggestions?

---

Update: technomage pointed out that Apple now installs the JDK under `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, and the JNI headers were at `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h`.

But I'm still stuck on my actual goal, which is to build the JNI wrappers for LevelDB (per instructions at github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni). To point Maven at the proper JDK, I added `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin` to the front of my PATH, and set JAVA_HOME to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home`. After chugging for a while, Maven now fails with:

```
[INFO] --- maven-hawtjni-plugin:1.5:build (default) @ leveldbjni-osx ---  
[INFO] Extracting /Users/steve/leveldb/leveldbjni/leveldbjni/target/leveldbjni-99-master-SNAPSHOT-native-src.zip to /Users/steve/leveldb/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-osx/target/native-build-extracted  
[INFO] executing: /bin/sh -c ./configure --disable-ccache --prefix=/Users/steve/leveldb/leveldbjni/leveldbjni-osx/target/native-build/target --with-leveldb=/Users/steve/leveldb/leveldb --with-snappy=/Users/steve/leveldb/snappy-1.0.3 --with-universal --with-leveldb=/Users/steve/leveldb/leveldb --with-snappy=/Users/steve/leveldb/snappy-1.0.3  
...  
[INFO] configure: JAVA_HOME was set, checking to see if it's a JDK we can use...  
[INFO] checking if '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home' is a JDK... no  
[INFO] configure: javac was on your path, checking to see if it's part of a JDK we can use...  
[INFO] checking if '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home' is a JDK... no  
[INFO] configure: Taking a guess as to where your OS installs the JDK by default...  
[INFO] checking if '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework' is a JDK... no  
[INFO] configure: error: JDK not found. Please use the --with-jni-jdk option
```

I can't tell for sure what Maven is looking at to identify "a JDK we can use"? Some digging around led me to http://www.arm4.org/trac/browser/branches/architecture/m4/jni.m4 which appears to look for jni.h in a few places and try to compile it, but I don't know whether this jni.m4 has any actual relationship Maven. I do have jni.h in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/.

Comment: jni.m4 is probably related to OpenJDK (upon which the OSX version is based).  Check to see if maven has been updated to account for the new OSX JDK path/version, and whether your maven is up-to-date (macports is probably the easiest way to update it).

Comment: I reinstalled maven from macports... that got me a little farther, but then the build died in a flurry of header files not found. After much further flailing I eventually got it to build. The big remaining problem, I think, was that Apple has moved the SDKs directory. I patched around that by symlinking /Developer/SDKs to /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I've heard reports of other developers moving to 1.7 on OSX and having issues with JNI headers being lost, incorrectly symlinked, or just generally messed up.  A number of tools depend on the old framework layout (since it was the recommended way by Apple), so expect a bit of an upheaval as everything now has to adjust to the Oracle version.

Answer (score 11):

I know this is an old thread, but here is what I did to get current today (Late 3/14)  so I could build some Ruby GEM that needed the Java Headers. Overkill, but covers all the bases, I think.

1. Download the Java 8 JDK from
   http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html
2. Install it.
3. See where Oracle put it:

   ```
   $/usr/libexec/java_home
   /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home
   ```
4. Symlink from there to where Apple used to put it:

   ```
   $cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
   $sudo ln -nsf /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents ./CurrentJDK
   ```
5. Symlink to make a Headers directory in JavaVM.framewrk:

   ```
   $cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework
   $sudo ln -nsf Versions/CurrentJDK/Home/include/ ./Headers
   ```

This fixed things for me. I haven't bothered with defining `JAVA_HOME` yet because I haven't needed it.

Comment: This worked for building some Hadoop tools that use JNI, thanks!

Comment: This symlinking seems to be blocked by macOS 10.11 and higher :(

Comment: Dang. Guess you have to turn off System Integrity Protection these days. Ugh.

Comment: This method of linking no longer works with OSX 12.4 Monterey.  You are not allowed to drop symlinks under System even as root.
bash-3.2# sudo ln -s /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/temurin-11.jdk/Contents/Home/include Headers
ln: Headers: Operation not permitted
bash-3.2# pwd
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A

Comment: Billions of years later we are on Mac OS Monterey, does this work on that? Nope.

Answer (score 5):

You probably need to install the Java Documentation package to get the headers; for the last few releases they have not been included in the JDK package.  After installation, they will show up in /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Headers.

[edit] Apple used to bundle the JNI headers with the JDK doc package.  This is no longer the case; the JNI headers *should* be bundled with the Java developer package.

[edit] Apple no longer bundles Java with its system, so you'll need to install a JDK from Oracle or OpenJDK.

Comment: Thanks... I looked around for a "Java Documentation package" download. The closest thing I could find was an option in XCode preferences, under "Documentation Sets", to download the "Mac OS X Java Library". Is that what you're referring to? It didn't cause the Headers directory to be created.

Comment: Note that developer.apple.com/downloads states that the "Java for Mac OS X 10.7 Developer Package" (which I downloaded originally) includes "documentation... and native framework headers". I find myself wondering whether the package simply didn't install correctly. But the installer didn't report any errors, and I don't see anything suspicious in the installer log.

Comment: They may be missing from the development package by mistake; this has happened before.  Report to apple (bugreporter.apple.com) which package they're missing from (the 9/28/11 or 2/15/12).  If you don't find them in either package, you'll need to install or copy from a previous package -- if you've got a previous SDK installed, look in /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.*.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/CurrentJDK/Headers/.

Comment: Additional info on recent packaging changes is here, including the move of headers from the documentation package - https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/Java/JavaSnowLeopardUpdate3LeopardUpdate8RN/NewandNoteworthy/NewandNoteworthy.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010380-CH4-SW1

Comment: BTW, you can run "locate jni.h" to see if there are *any* headers installed on your system.

Comment: Thanks! I had used Spotlight to look for jni.h files, but found nothing relevant. "locate" found better candidates, such as /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Headers/jni.h and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/include/jni.h. Unfortunately, I'm still stuck (see next comment).

Comment: My actual goal is to build the JNI wrappers for LevelDB (per instructions at https://github.com/fusesource/leveldbjni). Maven is failing to recognize the JDK, e.g. "checking if '/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework' is a JDK... no". I tried a few things, e.g. adding a symlink for the /include folder, but it didn't help. I'd be grateful for further help -- happy in return to help write up the solution here, or even to pay a consulting fee. You can reach me via the contact link at scalyr.com.

Comment: The /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines is the "new" path and the one you should reference.  Apple has deprecated the framework path.  It looks like your 1.7 installation *did* include the headers; the "Home" directory is the one you should indicate as JAVA_HOME (although maven may have some custom logic for finding it from the .jdk package).  Make sure that when you run maven, the "java" command in the path is the 1.7 one.

Comment: Thanks... I tried this, but I'm still stuck at the same point. I've added additional details in the main body of the question.

Comment: Hi steve did you manage to locate the headers? i could not find them myself

Comment: No longer the case in Mac OS Monterey in 2022